# Quickly applying string operations in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` with 100k rows and a column `name`. I would like to split this name into first and last name as efficiently as possibly. My current method is,

```
def splitName(name):
  return pandas.Series(name.split()[0:2])

df[['first', 'last']] = df.apply(lambda x: splitName(x['name']), axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, `DataFrame.apply` is really, really slow. Is there anything I can do to make this string operation nearly as fast as a `numpy` operation?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have pandas 0.8.1 or above, it looks like you should be able to do `series.str.split()`. Docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try (requires pandas >= 0.8.1):

```
splits = x['name'].split()
df['first'] = splits.str[0]
df['last'] = splits.str[1]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Didn't know about this addition.

Comment: Interestingly, this question is identical to [this later one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns) but the response has no mention of `Series.split()`. Has it been removed from `pandas`?

Comment: It is now available as `Series.str.split()`