# How to split text in a column into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a large csv file and the next to last column has a string of text that I want to split by a specific delimiter. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this using pandas or python?

```
CustNum  CustomerName     ItemQty  Item   Seatblocks                 ItemExt
32363    McCartney, Paul      3     F04    2:218:10:4,6                   60
31316    Lennon, John        25     F01    1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13     300
```

I want to split by the space `(' ')` and then the colon `(':')` in the `Seatblocks` column, but each cell would result in a different number of columns. I have a function to rearrange the columns so the `Seatblocks` column is at the end of the sheet, but I'm not sure what to do from there. I can do it in excel with the built in `text-to-columns` function and a quick macro, but my dataset has too many records for excel to handle.

Ultimately, I want to take records such John Lennon's and create multiple lines, with the info from each set of seats on a separate line.

Comment: this great question relates to FlatMap in pandas, which currently not exists

Comment: @cdarlint What is `FlatMap`?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

This splits the Seatblocks by space and gives each its own row.

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item                 Seatblocks  ItemExt
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04               2:218:10:4,6       60
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01  1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13      300

In [44]: s = df['Seatblocks'].str.split(' ').apply(Series, 1).stack()

In [45]: s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) # to line up with df's index

In [46]: s.name = 'Seatblocks' # needs a name to join

In [47]: s
Out[47]: 
0    2:218:10:4,6
1    1:13:36:1,12
1    1:13:37:1,13
Name: Seatblocks, dtype: object

In [48]: del df['Seatblocks']

In [49]: df.join(s)
Out[49]: 
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item  ItemExt    Seatblocks
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04       60  2:218:10:4,6
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:36:1,12
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:37:1,13
```

Or, to give each colon-separated string in its own column:

```
In [50]: df.join(s.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))
Out[50]: 
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item  ItemExt  0    1   2     3
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04       60  2  218  10   4,6
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1   13  36  1,12
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1   13  37  1,13
```

This is a little ugly, but maybe someone will chime in with a prettier solution.

Comment: @DanAllan give an index to the Series when you apply; they will become column names

Comment: This is a great answer. However `.str.split(' ').apply(Series, 1).stack()` may be problematic if the split() call does not return a list (i.e. when the string does not contain any spaces), the dtype of the column object will be a Series, and not a string.

Comment: While this answers the question, it is worth mentioning that (probably) split() creates a list for each row, which blows up the size of the `DataFrame` very quickly. In my case, running the code on a ~200M table resulted in ~10G memory (+swap...) usage.

Comment: Though I am not sure it is because of `split()`, because simply `reduce()`'ing through the column works like a charm. The problem then may lie in `stack()`...

Comment: I am getting the error `NameError: name 'Series' is not defined` for this. where is `Series` supposed to come from? EDIT: nevermind, it should be `pandas.Series` since it is referring to the item from `pandas`

Comment: Yep, @user5359531. I `from pandas import Series` for convenience/brevity.

Comment: tried to do this in a for loop so I could split up a bunch of files and it ended up freezing on me. That says to me that calling del on a column is a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: @Dan Allan, any idea why I am getting a memory error when trying to replicate this (the first part) and what I can do to fix that?

Comment: @David Nemeskey, do you know what is the way to bypass it? I got a MemoryError doing this and it took hours to get my computer up and running again

Comment: What does the `1` do in `.apply(pd.Series, 1)`? It can't be the `convert_dtype` argument from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html and I've observed that replacing it with `0` or `2` gives the same result. So does omitting it at all.

Answer (score 59):

Differently from Dan, I consider his answer quite elegant... but unfortunately it is also very very inefficient. So, since the question mentioned *"a large csv file"*, let me suggest to try in a shell Dan's solution:

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print df['col'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.split(' '))).head()"
```

... compared to this alternative:

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
from scipy import array, concatenate;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print pd.DataFrame(concatenate(df['col'].apply( lambda x : [x.split(' ')]))).head()"
```

... and this:

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(range(3), [df['col'].apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[i]) for i in range(3)]))).head()"
```

The second simply refrains from allocating 100 000 Series, and this is enough to make it around 10 times faster. But the third solution, which somewhat ironically wastes a lot of calls to str.split() (it is called once per column per row, so three times more than for the others two solutions), is around *40 times* faster than the first, because it even avoids to instance the 100 000 lists. And yes, it is certainly a little ugly...

**EDIT:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505089/2858145) suggests how to use "to_list()" and to avoid the need for a lambda. The result is something like

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split().tolist()).head()"
```

which is even more efficient than the third solution, and certainly much more elegant.

**EDIT:** the even simpler

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print pd.DataFrame(list(df.col.str.split())).head()"
```

works too, and is **almost** as efficient.

**EDIT:** [even simpler](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17902#issuecomment-337236716)! And handles NaNs (but less efficient):

```
time python -c "import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col']);
print df.col.str.split(expand=True).head()"
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the amount of memory that this method consumes and I'm wondering if you could give me a little advice. I have a DataFrame that contains about 8000 rows, each with a string containing 9216 space delimited 8-bit integers. This is roughly 75MB, but when I apply the last solution verbatim, Python eats 2GB of my memory. Can you point me in the direction of some source that would tell me why this is, and what I can do to get around it? Thanks.

Comment: You have a lot of lists and very small strings, which is more or less the worst case for memory usage in python (and the intermediate step ".split().tolist()" produces pure python objects). What I would probably do in your place would be to dump the DataFrame to a file, and then open it as csv with read_csv(..., sep=' '). But to stay on topic: the first solution (together with the third, which however should be awfully slow) may be the one offering you the lowest memory usage among the 4, since you have a relatively small number of relatively long rows.

Comment: Hey Pietro, I tried your suggestion of saving to a file and re-loading, an it worked quite well. I ran into some trouble when I tried to do this in a StringIO object, and a nice solution to my problem has been posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562869/pandas-unable-to-read-from-large-stringio-object).

Comment: Your last suggestion of `tolist()` is perfect. In my case I only wanted one of the pieces of data in the list and was able to directly add a single column to my existing df by using .ix: `df['newCol'] = pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split().tolist()).ix[:,2]`

Comment: Ahh, I was having trouble getting this to work at first - something about `obect of type 'float' has no len()` which was baffling, until I realized *some* of my rows had `NaN` in them, as opposed to `str`.

Answer (score 16):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemQty': {0: 3, 1: 25}, 
                   'Seatblocks': {0: '2:218:10:4,6', 1: '1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13'}, 
                   'ItemExt': {0: 60, 1: 300}, 
                   'CustomerName': {0: 'McCartney, Paul', 1: 'Lennon, John'}, 
                   'CustNum': {0: 32363, 1: 31316}, 
                   'Item': {0: 'F04', 1: 'F01'}}, 
                    columns=['CustNum','CustomerName','ItemQty','Item','Seatblocks','ItemExt'])

print (df)
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item                 Seatblocks  ItemExt
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04               2:218:10:4,6       60
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01  1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13      300
```

Another similar solution with chaining is use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html):

```
print (df.drop('Seatblocks', axis=1)
             .join
             (
             df.Seatblocks
             .str
             .split(expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('Seatblocks')           
             ))

   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item  ItemExt    Seatblocks
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04       60  2:218:10:4,6
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:36:1,12
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:37:1,13
```

---

If in column are **NOT** `NaN` values, the fastest solution is use `list` comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*100000, columns=['col'])

In [141]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(range(3), [df['col'].apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[i]) for i in range(3)]))))
1 loop, best of 3: 211 ms per loop

In [142]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.col.str.split().tolist()))
10 loops, best of 3: 87.8 ms per loop

In [143]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(list(df.col.str.split())))
10 loops, best of 3: 86.1 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit (df.col.str.split(expand=True))
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop

In [145]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([ x.split() for x in df['col'].tolist()]))
10 loops, best of 3: 54.1 ms per loop
```

But if column contains `NaN` only works [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `expand=True` which return `DataFrame` ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings)), and it explain why it is slowier:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a b c']*10, columns=['col'])
df.loc[0] = np.nan
print (df.head())
     col
0    NaN
1  a b c
2  a b c
3  a b c
4  a b c

print (df.col.str.split(expand=True))
     0     1     2
0  NaN  None  None
1    a     b     c
2    a     b     c
3    a     b     c
4    a     b     c
5    a     b     c
6    a     b     c
7    a     b     c
8    a     b     c
9    a     b     c
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that you necessarily need the `expand=True` option working with `pandas.DataFrames` while using `.str.split()` for example.

Comment: @holzkohlengrill - thank you for comment, I add it to answer.

Comment: @jezrael, it is taking me very long to execute this code, is that expected. How exactly do I make it faster? IF I put it in a for loop like: for x in df[Seablocks][:100] to only do it on a subset and then concatenate on these subsets, will that work?

Answer (score 12):

It may be late to answer this question but I hope to document 2 good features from Pandas: `pandas.Series.str.split()` with regular expression and `pandas.Series.explode()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'CustNum': [32363, 31316],
     'CustomerName': ['McCartney, Paul', 'Lennon, John'],
     'ItemQty': [3, 25],
     'Item': ['F04', 'F01'],
     'Seatblocks': ['2:218:10:4,6', '1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13'],
     'ItemExt': [60, 360]
    }
)

print(df)
print('-'*80+'\n')

df['Seatblocks'] = df['Seatblocks'].str.split('[ :]')
df = df.explode('Seatblocks').reset_index(drop=True)
cols = list(df.columns)
cols.append(cols.pop(cols.index('CustomerName')))
df = df[cols]


print(df)
print('='*80+'\n')
print(df[df['CustomerName'] == 'Lennon, John'])
```

The output is:

```
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item                 Seatblocks  ItemExt
0    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04               2:218:10:4,6       60
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01  1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13      360
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    CustNum  ItemQty Item Seatblocks  ItemExt     CustomerName
0     32363        3  F04          2       60  McCartney, Paul
1     32363        3  F04        218       60  McCartney, Paul
2     32363        3  F04         10       60  McCartney, Paul
3     32363        3  F04        4,6       60  McCartney, Paul
4     31316       25  F01          1      360     Lennon, John
5     31316       25  F01         13      360     Lennon, John
6     31316       25  F01         36      360     Lennon, John
7     31316       25  F01       1,12      360     Lennon, John
8     31316       25  F01          1      360     Lennon, John
9     31316       25  F01         13      360     Lennon, John
10    31316       25  F01         37      360     Lennon, John
11    31316       25  F01       1,13      360     Lennon, John
================================================================================

    CustNum  ItemQty Item Seatblocks  ItemExt  CustomerName
4     31316       25  F01          1      360  Lennon, John
5     31316       25  F01         13      360  Lennon, John
6     31316       25  F01         36      360  Lennon, John
7     31316       25  F01       1,12      360  Lennon, John
8     31316       25  F01          1      360  Lennon, John
9     31316       25  F01         13      360  Lennon, John
10    31316       25  F01         37      360  Lennon, John
11    31316       25  F01       1,13      360  Lennon, John
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems a far easier method than those suggested elsewhere in this thread.

[split rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523316/split-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be like this:

```
temp = df['Seatblocks'].str.split(' ')
data = data.reindex(data.index.repeat(temp.apply(len)))
data['new_Seatblocks'] = np.hstack(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use groupby() with no need to join and stack().

Use above example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemQty': {0: 3, 1: 25}, 
                   'Seatblocks': {0: '2:218:10:4,6', 1: '1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13'}, 
                   'ItemExt': {0: 60, 1: 300}, 
                   'CustomerName': {0: 'McCartney, Paul', 1: 'Lennon, John'}, 
                   'CustNum': {0: 32363, 1: 31316}, 
                   'Item': {0: 'F04', 1: 'F01'}}, 
                    columns=['CustNum','CustomerName','ItemQty','Item','Seatblocks','ItemExt']) 
print(df)

   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item                 Seatblocks  ItemExt
0  32363    McCartney, Paul  3        F04  2:218:10:4,6               60     
1  31316    Lennon, John     25       F01  1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13  300  


#first define a function: given a Series of string, split each element into a new series
def split_series(ser,sep):
    return pd.Series(ser.str.cat(sep=sep).split(sep=sep)) 
#test the function, 
split_series(pd.Series(['a b','c']),sep=' ')
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

df2=(df.groupby(df.columns.drop('Seatblocks').tolist()) #group by all but one column
          ['Seatblocks'] #select the column to be split
          .apply(split_series,sep=' ') # split 'Seatblocks' in each group
         .reset_index(drop=True,level=-1).reset_index()) #remove extra index created

print(df2)
   CustNum     CustomerName  ItemQty Item  ItemExt    Seatblocks
0    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:36:1,12
1    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:37:1,13
2    32363  McCartney, Paul        3  F04       60  2:218:10:4,6
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. How I could use the above code by splitting two columns correpsindingly. For Example: 0    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13     A,B.. The result should be: `0    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:36:1,12      A` and next line   `0    31316     Lennon, John       25  F01      300  1:13:37:1,13      B`

Comment: @Krithi.S, I try to understand the question. Do you mean the two columns must have same number of members after splitting? What is your expected results for 0 31316 Lennon, John 25 F01 300 1:13:36:1,12 1:13:37:1,13 A,B,C    ?