# Denormalise the data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, sparse-matrix

If I have data of the following format (stored in a pandas dataframe), essentially a normalised form of categories and wares to a slug:

```
pandas.DataFrame:

                                 categories                      slug                                              wares
0                     [developer, mac, web]                alex.payne  [macbook-pro, cinema-display, readynas-nv-plus...
1                           [mac, musician]             jona.bechtolt  [audio-kontrol-1, powershot-sd1000, live, mda-...
2                     [game, suit, windows]               gabe.newell  [oa-desk, beyond-tv, windows-xp, office, visua...
3                [developer, mac, software]              steven.frank  [mac-pro, macbook-air, apple-tv, itunes, addre...
```

And my intension is to plot graphs of categories correlated with wares, I'd need the data in a denormalised format, in some such format:

```
    categories  wares   slug
0    developer   macbook-pro     alex.payne
1    mac     macbook-pro     alex.payne
2    web     macbook-pro     alex.payne
3    developer   cinema-display  alex.payne
4    mac     cinema-display  alex.payne
5    web     cinema-display  alex.payne
6    developer   readynas-nv-plus    alex.payne
```

What is the best way to convert the data from the format above to the one below, preferably the one, that also leverages the internals of numpy, so it is fast.

My approach was to this was rather a naive one, looping through each row in the data frame, maintaining a list of tuples and then passing it over to the pandas.DataFrame constructor. Any suggestion of yours will probably end up being faster and better, so suggest away!

I am also thinking about alternative representations of such a data in the pandas DataFrame, specifically, a sparse matrix. But I think this would be better particularly for groupby queries. If there are other formats or if sparse matrix renders it better for such aggregation queries, suggest how to go about it.

Here is the entire thing, for those interested: http://j.mp/lp-usesthis I ended up not doing the denormalisation the way I originally intended, instead looped over column of interest only. But any ability to denormalise better would make it better.

Comment: can u show your current code?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns/17116976#17116976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I strongly recommend that you don't store you data like this in the first place, pandas isn't really meant for general objects like lists.

Here's one way to extract the data (using joins, [similar to Dan Allen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns/17116976#17116976)).

```
def denormalise(df, *colnames):
    df1 = df.copy() #  optional, but means we're not changing df globally
    cols = [(colname, df1.pop(colname).apply(pd.Series).stack()) for colname in colnames]
    for colname, c in cols:
        c.index = c.index.droplevel(-1)
        c.name = colname
        df1 = df1.join(c)
    return df1
    # optionally .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)  # reorder columns
    #        and .reset_index(drop=True)            # 0,1,...n index
```

In use:

```
In [11]: denormalise(df1, 'wares')
Out[11]:
              categories           slug             wares
0  [developer, mac, web]     alex.payne       macbook-pro
0  [developer, mac, web]     alex.payne    cinema-display
0  [developer, mac, web]     alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus
1        [mac, musician]  jona.bechtolt   audio-kontrol-1
1        [mac, musician]  jona.bechtolt  powershot-sd1000
1        [mac, musician]  jona.bechtolt              live
```

Pandas allows you to add this as a DataFrame method for convenience:

```
In [12]: pd.DataFrame.denormalise = denormalise

In [13]: df1.denormalise('wares', 'categories')
Out[13]:
            slug             wares categories
0     alex.payne       macbook-pro  developer
0     alex.payne       macbook-pro        mac
0     alex.payne       macbook-pro        web
0     alex.payne    cinema-display  developer
0     alex.payne    cinema-display        mac
0     alex.payne    cinema-display        web
0     alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus  developer
0     alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus        mac
0     alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus        web
1  jona.bechtolt   audio-kontrol-1        mac
1  jona.bechtolt   audio-kontrol-1   musician
1  jona.bechtolt  powershot-sd1000        mac
1  jona.bechtolt  powershot-sd1000   musician
1  jona.bechtolt              live        mac
1  jona.bechtolt              live   musician

In [14]: df1.denormalise('wares', 'categories').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[14]:
             slug             wares categories
0      alex.payne       macbook-pro  developer
1      alex.payne       macbook-pro        mac
2      alex.payne       macbook-pro        web
3      alex.payne    cinema-display  developer
4      alex.payne    cinema-display        mac
5      alex.payne    cinema-display        web
6      alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus  developer
7      alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus        mac
8      alex.payne  readynas-nv-plus        web
9   jona.bechtolt   audio-kontrol-1        mac
10  jona.bechtolt   audio-kontrol-1   musician
11  jona.bechtolt  powershot-sd1000        mac
12  jona.bechtolt  powershot-sd1000   musician
13  jona.bechtolt              live        mac
14  jona.bechtolt              live   musician
```