# How to split a column based on several string indices using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split each row into new columns based on several indices:

```
6ABCDE0218594STRING
```

to

```
6 ABCDE 021 8594 STRING
```

This seems like it'd have been asked at least once before, but I keep finding only variations on the question (separating by a delimiter as in [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-columns), separating into new rows using rather than new columns, again with a delimiter: [Split pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)).

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate!

Comment: You can select parts of a string with simply use 'df.new=df.originallongstring.str()[1:5]' (untested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a regex and [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) to pull out the columns:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['6ABCDE0218594STRING']])
```

You could just do it with index, so something like this:

```
In [12]: df[0].str.extract('(.)(.{5})(.{3})(.{4})(.*)')
Out[12]:
   0      1    2     3       4
0  6  ABCDE  021  8594  STRING
```

Or you could be a bit more cautious and ensure each column is the correct form:

```
In [13]: df[0].str.extract('(\d)(.{5})(\d{3})(\d{4})(.*)')
Out[13]:
   0      1    2     3       4
0  6  ABCDE  021  8594  STRING
```

*Note: You can also use named groups (see [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html)).*

Comment: Thank you! I'm working on this now -- had a bit of a hiccup because I was using pandas 0.12.

Comment: @Andy Hayden is there a way I can replicate this to a large set on indices on to a data frame?

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to convert strings consisting of only spaces into NaNs.  Is there a way to avoid that, or should I just convert NaNs back to spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = '6ABCDE0218594STRING'
indices = [1,5,3,4]
myList = []

for index in indices:
    token, string = string[:index],string[index:]
    myList.append(token)

myList.append(string)

>>> Output: ['6', 'ABCDE', '021', '8594', 'STRING']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in case you don't know the number of digits, letters etc.:

```py
import re

m = re.match('(\d*)([A-Z]*)(\d*)([A-Z]*)', '6ABCDE0218594STRING').groups()
print m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3]
```

Output:

```
6 ABCDE 0218594 STRING
```

Comment: Yeah, regex is great! However, one issue with this particular application is that I will often need to break up a series of integers too (e.g. 0123456 -> 012 34 56).

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that one number is split up. Then it is, of course, not working as required. :)