# yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00 to yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I believe that my problem is really straightfoward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue with pandas that I am still not aware of.

The problem is that I have one column on a pandas dataframe which all the elements are written on this following format:

```
 yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00
```

I want to translate each element of the column to the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00
```

And also, afterwards, is it possible from this column of the dataframe, create two more columns now dividing into date and time. What I mean is, to get:

```
yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00
```

to two more columns, one containing the date:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

And the other containing the time:

```
00:00:00
```

Hope that I could synthetize everything properly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string into several columns in a dataframe with pandas Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958282/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-several-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-08-29T12:00:00']})

#                   Date
# 0  2019-08-29T12:00:00

df.Date.str.split('T', expand=True)

#             0         1
# 0  2019-08-29  12:00:00
```

To simply get rid of the `T` between date and time string, you could use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.Date.str.replace('T', ' ')

# 0    2019-08-29 12:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you SpghttCd. Do you also know how would it work if I wanted to put the data on this format - yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 - on the same column?