# How can I apply classification algorithm for text data which is in the form of numerical tokens?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, text-classification, tf-idf, naivebayes

I am trying to work on a classification problem: The data is of reviews of a particular product category from an e-commerce platform. Please find below the description of each attribute:

- **id**: Unique identifier for each tuple.
- **category**: The reviews have been categorized into two categories representing positive and negative reviews. 0 represents positive reviews and 1 represents negative reviews.
- **text**: Tokenized text content of the review.

The sample dataset is attached in the picture.

[image: image contains the training data format which consists of the above said columns]

I am thinking to try TF-IDF however, given the text format don't know how to use the same.

I expect to predict the category based on the text column provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column `text`as several features, I would recommend you to split that column ([How do I split a string into several columns in a dataframe with pandas Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958282/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-several-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-pandas-python)):

```
#first load dataframe (I assume it is excel format)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YourPath', header=True)
df['Text'].str.split('', expand=True)
```

then you can conver it to a (0,1) dataframe:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['id', 'category']).stack())
         .max(level=0)
         .rename(columns=int)
         .reset_index())
```

this will leads to something like:

```
id category 5002  7400 ....
 1    A         1     0 .....
 2   B         0     1
```

where the columns are the values from your dataframe, and only filled if the value exists in that category

Comment: Yes, but if I split them then the length of the data is not constant and hence will get multiple columns with empty values of maximum rows.

Comment: you can check out this for the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027455/transform-cell-values-as-column-headers-and-fill-it-with-1-if-matching-in-python

Comment: @DhrubSatyamJha did you get any solution?