# Transform cell values as column headers and fill it with 1 if matching in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df
ID 0   1   2    3  4 .... 
1  10  20  5    1  2 ....
2  3   4   NaN    10 1 ....
```

And I need to transpose the cell values of the column `0,1,2,3,4...` to the column headers, and fill it for the Id's with 1 if the cell value is present for the respective ID.

Desired Output:

```
ID 1 2 3 4 5 ... 10 20 ..
1  1 1 0 0 1 ... 1  1  ..
2  1 0 1 1 0 ... 1  0  ..
```

Note that some entries can be `NaN`.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: what? The ID column I need to keep

Comment: Answer edited for 2 possible solutions - indicator vs count values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove missing values, then create indicators by [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and return `1/0` by `max` by first level, last convert columns to integers:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID').stack())
         .max(level=0)
         .rename(columns=int)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   ID  1  2  3  4  5  10  20
0   1  1  1  0  0  1   1   1
1   2  1  0  1  1  0   1   0
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   ID   0   1    2   3  4  5
0   1  10  20  5.0   1  2  5
1   2   3   4  NaN  10  1  2
```

If use `max` then always in output are `0/1` values (check 5 column):

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID').stack())
         .max(level=0)
         .rename(columns=int)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   ID  1  2  3  4  5  10  20
0   1  1  1  0  0  1   1   1
1   2  1  1  1  1  0   1   0
```

But if use `sum` it count values (check 5 column):

```
df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID').stack())
         .sum(level=0)
         .rename(columns=int)
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
   ID  1  2  3  4  5  10  20
0   1  1  1  0  0  2   1   1
1   2  1  1  1  1  0   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `melt` and `pd.crosstab`

```
df1 = df.melt('ID')
df_final =  pd.crosstab(index=df1.ID, columns=df1.value).reset_index()

Out[673]:
value  ID  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  10.0  20.0
0      1   1    1    0    0    1    1     1
1      2   1    0    1    1    0    1     0
```

---

**Note**: default counting of `pd.crosstab` uses frequency. Therefore, duplicate values will count as their frequencies. If you want only `1/0` indicator, just chain `ge(1)` and `astype` as follows

```
pd.crosstab(index=df1.ID, columns=df1.value).ge(1).astype(int).reset_index()
```