# Pandas - convert list to string & Wide to Long with one column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My dataframe `df` looks like this, the `ID` column is a list.

```
Name     Title     ID
ED       HHH     [11111, 11112, 11113, 11114]
AD       BBB     [11119, 11133]
```

I want to first convert column `ID` to a string, since I'm assuming that is how I would want the column to move on to the next step. Next step would be to basically opposite of a pivot table the dataframe `df` to look like below.

I would like my dataframe `df` to look like this

```
   Name     Title     ID
    ED       HHH     11111
    ED       HHH     11112
    ED       HHH     11113
    ED       HHH     11114
    AD       BBB     11119
    AD       BBB     11133
```

I've tried

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.split(', ')
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.join(map(str,df['ID']))
df['ID'] = str(df['ID']).strip(', ')
df['ID'] = ''.join(str(x) for x in df['ID'])
```

and it does not give me what I'm looking for or it uses up too much RAM and locks my computer.

Any help or tips? Do I even have to convert the list to a string first to put it in my desired output?

Comment: Just to double-check, what do you get for type(df['ID'].values[0]) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following this answer [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows)

In your case there would be a slight modification as noted below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# since you have a column of lists skip any type of string munging
# instead, go straight to converting the lists to a Series
s = df['ID'].apply(Series,1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'ID'
del df['ID']
df = df.join(s)
```

Please note this example completely ignores the index of your DataFrame; you may need to update or `reset_index()`.