# How to split pandas column by a delimiter and select preferred element as the replacement

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'gene':["1 // foo // blabla",
                                   "2 // bar // lalala",
                                   "3 // qux // trilil",
                                   "4 // woz // hohoho"], 'cell1':[5,9,1,7], 'cell2':[12,90,13,87]})
df = source_df[["gene","cell1","cell2"]]
```

It looks like this:

```
                 gene  cell1  cell2
0  1 // foo // blabla      5     12
1  2 // bar // lalala      9     90
2  3 // qux // trilil      1     13
3  4 // woz // hohoho      7     87
```

What I want to get is this:

```
   gene    cell1  cell2
0   foo       5     12
1   bar       9     90
2   qux       1     13
3   woz       7     87
```

Namely select 2nd element of the splited string by `//` as delimiter.

The best I can do is this:

```
df["gene"] = df["gene"].str.split(" // ")
df
Out[17]:
               gene  cell1  cell2
0  [1, foo, blabla]      5     12
1  [2, bar, lalala]      9     90
2  [3, qux, trilil]      1     13
3  [4, woz, hohoho]      7     87
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: See: [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) this will be much faster than using `apply` on a large dataset:

```
In [13]:
df['gene'] = df['gene'].str.split('//').str[1]
df

Out[13]:
   cell1  cell2   gene
0      5     12   foo 
1      9     90   bar 
2      1     13   qux 
3      7     87   woz
```

Comment: Interesting that appling a string method to a list has the desired results. How did you come out with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regex` and strip first and last spaces by `strip`:

```
df["gene"] = df["gene"].str.extract(r"\/\/([a-z ]+)\/\/")
df["gene"] = df["gene"].str.strip()

print df
  gene  cell1  cell2
0  foo      5     12
1  bar      9     90
2  qux      1     13
3  woz      7     87
```

`\/\/([a-z ]+)\/\/` means:

```
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    1st Capturing group ([a-z ]+)
        [a-z ]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
            giving back as needed [greedy]
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
             the literal character  
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
```

Or regex without strip:

```
df["gene"] = df["gene"].str.extract(r"\/\/\s*([a-z ]+)\s\/\/")
```

`/\/\/\s*([a-z ]+)\s\/\//` means:

```
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
        giving back as needed [greedy]
    1st Capturing group ([a-z ]+)
        [a-z ]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
            giving back as needed [greedy]
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
            the literal character  
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
```

Comment: if you put \s* outside both ends of the group there's no need to strip.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, however selecting the element from the resulting split is a bit more difficult doing it your way.

Here's a solution with apply

```
>>> df['gene'] = df['gene'].apply(lambda s: s.split('//')[1])
>>> df

    gene  cell1  cell2
0   foo       5     12
1   bar       9     90
2   qux       1     13
3   woz       7     87
```

Comment: when I compared this to the top solution, this one turned out to be faster, even though in theory vectorized operations should be faster than apply. Interesting.