# Split rows according to text in two columns (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, multi-index

This is my dataframe (with many more letters and a length of ~35.5k) and stuff where the – are other relevant strings). All the variables are strings and ['C1','C2'] is the MultiIndex.

```
tmp

C1    C2     C3    C4    C5    Start    End     C8
A     1      -      -     -    12       14      -
A     2      -      -     -    1,4,7    3,6,10  -
A     3      -      -     -    16,19    17,21   -
A     4      -      -     -    22       24      -
```

I need it to become this (split every row that contains commas maintaining everything else):

```
C1    C2     C3    C4    C5    Start  End   C8   Appearance
A     1      -      -     -    12     14    -    1
A     2      -      -     -    1      3     -    1
A     2      -      -     -    4      6     -    2
A     2      -      -     -    7      10    -    3
A     3      -      -     -    16     17    -    1
A     3      -      -     -    19     21    -    2
A     4      -      -     -    22     24    -    1
```

I tried this script
[pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows)

as

```
s = tmp['Start'].str.split(',').apply(Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'Start
del tmp['Start']
final = tmp.join(s)
```

But then the result is much larger than it should! I get thousands of repeats and this is just trying to split 'Start'. I can't even imagine trying to do so for both Start and End (every comma in 'Start' implies a comma in 'End'.

```
Lengths:
tmp   = 35568
s     = 35676
final = 293408
```

Comment: Isn't this expected? If you have [1, 4, 7] in a row, you will have two additional rows in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new `df` from `s1` and `s2` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Also better is use parameter `expand=True` in [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and delete multiple columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

For creating column `Appearance` use `groupby` by `index` with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

```
s1 = tmp['Start'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
s1.index = s1.index.droplevel(-1)
s1.name = 'Start'

s2 = tmp['End'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
s2.index = s2.index.droplevel(-1)
s2.name = 'End'
tmp.drop(['Start', 'End'], inplace=True, axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'s1':s1, 's2':s2}, index=s1.index)
final = tmp.join(df)

final['Appearance'] = final.groupby(final.index).cumcount() + 1
print (final)
  C1  C2 C3 C4 C5 C8  s1  s2  Appearance
0  A   1  -  -  -  -  12  14           1
1  A   2  -  -  -  -   1   3           1
1  A   2  -  -  -  -   4   6           2
1  A   2  -  -  -  -   7  10           3
2  A   3  -  -  -  -  16  17           1
2  A   3  -  -  -  -  19  21           2
3  A   4  -  -  -  -  22  24           1
```

EDIT by comment:

You can try `reset_index` first:

```
print (tmp)
      C3 C4 C5  Start     End C8
C1 C2                           
A  1   -  -  -     12      14  -
   2   -  -  -  1,4,7  3,6,10  -
   3   -  -  -  16,19   17,21  -
   4   -  -  -     22      24  -

tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (tmp)
  C1  C2 C3 C4 C5  Start     End C8
0  A   1  -  -  -     12      14  -
1  A   2  -  -  -  1,4,7  3,6,10  -
2  A   3  -  -  -  16,19   17,21  -
3  A   4  -  -  -     22      24  -
```

Comment: "[293408 rows x 7 columns]" Shouldn't it have the same amount of rows as s1/s2? (~35k)

Comment: Is length `s1` and `s2` same? is index of `s1` same as index of `s2`?

Comment: Yes! Every comma in Start implies a comma in End.

Comment: Maybe there are duplicates in index - try first use - `tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: It works!!! I'm sure the other answer also works but since you were first I'll tick you. Thanks to both. Could you also help me to add the 'Appearance' column?

Comment: Thank you. Please give me a time, I add column.

Comment: And maybe you forget tick solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why it was unticked, I swear it was ticked! By the way: your method for adding the Appearence column is counting each C2 item universally instead of locally (grouped by C1 items). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Ia m not sure if understand - what is difference between `universally` and `locally` ?

Comment: Already fixed it! I  needed to index by C1,C2,C3 instead of C1,C2 (which gives away Appearance.max() = 64 instead of 8).

Answer (score 2):

I concat the expanded `'Start'` and `'End'` columns to ensure they match up even if they don't have the same number of entries.

```
s = tmp.Start.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().rename('Start')
e = tmp.End.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().rename('End')
se = pd.concat([s, e], axis=1).reset_index(1, drop=True)

tmp.drop(['Start', 'End'], axis=1).merge(se, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: `TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'`

Comment: @Nico drop the argument.  You are using an older pandas version.

Comment: Your answer is nice too ;) +1

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'`

Comment: @Nico Sorry I can't fix that for you other than to suggest upgrading you pandas to 0.18.1 and try jezrael's solution or mine again.

Comment: Both use the same function. I'll try to update it in a few minutes and then I'll try again.