# Python Pandas: Split slash separated strings in two or more columns into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
SUBJECT                 STUDENT         CITY        STATE

Math/Chemistry/Biology  Sam/Peter/Mary  Los Angeles CA
Geology/Physics         John            Boston      MA
```

This is how it should look like:

```
SUBJECT      STUDENT    CITY           STATE

Math         Sam        Los Angeles    CA
Chemistry    Peter      Los Angeles    CA
Biology      Mary       Los Angeles    CA
Geology      John       Boston         MA
Physics      John       Boston         MA
```

Before asking this question, I referred to the solutions mentioned in this page: 
[pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows)

Since there are slash separated strings in two columns, I am not able to use the solutions in the above link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s1 = df.SUBJECT.str.split('/', expand=True).stack()
s2 = df.STUDENT.str.split('/', expand=True).stack()
print (s1)
0  0         Math
   1    Chemistry
   2      Biology
1  0      Geology
   1      Physics

print (s2)
0  0      Sam
   1    Peter
   2     Mary
1  0     John
dtype: object
```

```
df1 = pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1, keys=('SUBJECT','STUDENT'))
        .ffill()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df1)
     SUBJECT STUDENT
0       Math     Sam
0  Chemistry   Peter
0    Biology    Mary
1    Geology    John
1    Physics    John

df = df.drop(['SUBJECT','STUDENT'], axis=1)
       .join(df1)
       .reset_index(drop=True)[['SUBJECT', 'STUDENT', 'CITY','STATE']]
print (df)
     SUBJECT STUDENT         CITY STATE
0       Math     Sam  Los Angeles    CA
1  Chemistry   Peter  Los Angeles    CA
2    Biology    Mary  Los Angeles    CA
3    Geology    John       Boston    MA
4    Physics    John       Boston    MA
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing, split fields by `'/'`

```
df.SUBJECT = df.SUBJECT.str.split('/')
df.STUDENT = df.STUDENT.str.split('/')
```

Then I use a function to explode rows.  However, I had to segregate those rows that only had one student or subject.

```
def explode(df, columns):
    idx = np.repeat(df.index, df[columns[0]].str.len())
    a = df.T.reindex_axis(columns).values
    concat = np.concatenate([np.concatenate(a[i]) for i in range(a.shape[0])])
    p = pd.DataFrame(concat.reshape(a.shape[0], -1).T, idx, columns)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns, axis=1), p], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)


cond = df.STUDENT.str.len() == df.SUBJECT.str.len()

df_paired = df[cond]
df_unpard = df[~cond]

if not df_paired.empty:
    df_paired = explode(df_paired, ['STUDENT','SUBJECT'])

if not df_unpard.empty:
    df_unpard = explode(explode(df_unpard, ['STUDENT']), ['SUBJECT'])
```

Finally

```
pd.concat([df_paired, df_unpard], ignore_index=True)[df.columns]
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

***piRSquared***

```
%%timeit

df = df_.copy()

df.SUBJECT = df.SUBJECT.str.split('/')
df.STUDENT = df.STUDENT.str.split('/')

def explode(df, columns):
    idx = np.repeat(df.index, df[columns[0]].str.len())
    a = df.T.reindex_axis(columns).values
    concat = np.concatenate([np.concatenate(a[i]) for i in range(a.shape[0])])
    p = pd.DataFrame(concat.reshape(a.shape[0], -1).T, idx, columns)
    return pd.concat([df.drop(columns, axis=1), p], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

cond = df.STUDENT.str.len() == df.SUBJECT.str.len()

df_paired = df[cond]
df_unpard = df[~cond]

if not df_paired.empty:
    df_paired = explode(df_paired, ['STUDENT','SUBJECT'])

if not df_unpard.empty:
    df_unpard = explode(explode(df_unpard, ['STUDENT']), ['SUBJECT'])

pd.concat([df_paired, df_unpard], ignore_index=True)[df.columns]

100 loops, best of 3: 7.76 ms per loop
```

---

***jezrael***

```
%%timeit

df = df_.copy()

s1 = df.SUBJECT.str.split('/', expand=True).stack()
s2 = df.STUDENT.str.split('/', expand=True).stack()

df1 = pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1, keys=('SUBJECT','STUDENT')) \
        .ffill() \
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df.drop(['SUBJECT','STUDENT'], axis=1) \
  .join(df1) \
  .reset_index(drop=True)[['SUBJECT', 'STUDENT', 'CITY','STATE']]

100 loops, best of 3: 5.13 ms per loop
```

Comment: I see some numpy function - now it is faster as stack-join method?

Comment: :-) give me a stack join and lets see.

Comment: Ok, I add solution, please add timings ;)

Comment: @jezrael Yours is better.  I'm using a general purpose function to explode stuff.  I think I'm going to tweak it.  I really like how you did it.  You gain some efficiency by `expand=True` at the split step.  I'll end up moving the split into my function and doing that too.

Comment: Hmmm, I think if columns have same items in eaxh row, your solution can be faster. Thank you for timings.

Comment: @jezrael Yes, very likely.  I had to force the use of my function a bit.

Comment: I think if use numpy stuff it can be doog approach for improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Can be modified where `SUBJECT` equals 1 and `zip` is then used.

```
df3.SUBJECT = df3.SUBJECT.str.split('/')
df3.STUDENT = df3.STUDENT.str.split('/')

def splitter(gb):
    ll = []
    subs, stus = gb.SUBJECT.values[0], gb.STUDENT.values[0]

    if   len(stus) == len(subs): ll = zip(subs,stus)
    elif len(stus) == 1:         ll = zip(subs,stus*len(subs))
    return pd.DataFrame(ll, columns= (["SUBJECT","STUDENT"])) 

df = df3.groupby(['CITY','STATE'])['SUBJECT','STUDENT'].apply(splitter).reset_index().drop('level_2', axis =1)
print df[[ 'SUBJECT', 'STUDENT', 'CITY','STATE' ]]


   SUBJECT STUDENT        CITY STATE
0    Geology    John      Boston    MA
1    Physics    John      Boston    MA
2       Math     Sam  LosAngeles    CA
3  Chemistry   Peter  LosAngeles    CA
4    Biology    Mary  LosAngeles    CA
```