# sort one giant string into 7 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file which I read in as a string. In sublime the file looks like this:

```
Filename
Dataset
Level
Duration
Accuracy
Speed Ratio
Completed
file_001.mp3
datasetname_here
value
00:09:29
0.00%
7.36x
2019-07-18
file_002.mp3
datasetname_here
value
00:22:01
...etc.
```

in Bash:

```
['Filename\n', 'Dataset\n', 'Level\n', 'Duration\n', 'Accuracy\n', 'Speed Ratio\n', 'Completed\n', 'file_001.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'value\n', '00:09:29\n', '0.00%\n', '7.36x\n', '2019-07-18\n', 'file_002.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'L1\n', '00:20:01\n', ...etc.
```

I want to split this into a 7 column csv. As you can see, the values repeat every 8th line. I know I can use a for loop and modulus to read each line. I have done this successfully before.

How can I use pandas to read things into columns?

I don't know how to approach the Pandas library. I have looked at other examples and all seem to start with csv.

```
import sys 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file' , help = "this is the file you want to open")

args = parser.parse_args()
print("file name:" , args.file)

with open(args.file , 'r') as word:
    print(word.readlines())  ###here is where i was making sure it read in properly

###here is where I will start to manipulate the data
```

**This is the Bash output:**

```
['Filename\n', 'Dataset\n', 'Level\n', 'Duration\n', 'Accuracy\n', 'Speed Ratio\n', 'Completed\n', 'file_001.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'value\n', '00:09:29\n', '0.00%\n', '7.36x\n', '2019-07-18\n', 'file_002.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'L1\n', '00:20:01\n', ...]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting rows into multiple columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363314/splitting-rows-into-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove '\n':

```
raw_data = ['Filename\n', 'Dataset\n', 'Level\n', 'Duration\n', 'Accuracy\n', 'Speed Ratio\n', 'Completed\n', 'file_001.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'value\n', '00:09:29\n', '0.00%\n', '7.36x\n', '2019-07-18\n', 'file_002.mp3\n', 'datasetname_here\n', 'L1\n', '00:20:01\n', '0.01%\n', '7.39x\n', '2019-07-20\n']
raw_data = [string.replace('\n', '') for string in raw_data]
```

Then pack your data in 7-length arrays inside a big array:

```
data = [raw_data[x:x+7] for x in range(0, len(raw_data),7)]
```

Finally read your data as a DataFrame, the first row contains the name of the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df.to_string())

       Filename           Dataset  Level  Duration Accuracy Speed Ratio   Completed
0  file_001.mp3  datasetname_here  value  00:09:29    0.00%       7.36x  2019-07-18
1  file_002.mp3  datasetname_here     L1  00:20:01    0.01%       7.39x  2019-07-20
```

Comment: Why have you put in the data in line one? ['Filename\n' , 'Dataset\n' ...] I will be loading in strings of arbitratry length

```raw_data = word```

Will this not work?

Comment: The `raw_data` is your bash output but you can easily adapt this if you get the words one by one by just appending the words to a list.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
with open ("data.txt") as f:
    list_str = f.readlines()
list_str = map(lambda s: s.strip(), list_str) #Remove \n
n=7
list_str = [list_str[k:k+n] for k in range(0, len(list_str), n)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_str[1:])
df.columns = list_str[0]
df.to_csv("Data_generated.csv",index=False)
```

> [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is not a library to read into columns. It supports many formats to read and write (One of them is comma separated values) and mainly used as python based data analysis tool.
>   Best place to learn is see their documentation and practice.
>
> ### Output of above code
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use pandas or any other library. My approach:

```
data = []
row = []
with open(args.file , 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        row.append(line)
        if len(row) == 7:
            data.append(row)
            row = []
```

**How does it work?**

- The for loop reads the file line by line.
- Add the line to row
- When row's length is 7, it's completed and you can add the row to data
- Create a new list for row
  Repeat