# Pandas dataframe: Expanding column into rows plus incremental numbering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to expand a single row of my Pandas dataframe intwo multiple rows based on splitting the `score` column (containing match results) based on the spaces.

This is what the data looks like

```
A   B   score
1   2   6-1 6-2
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3
```

To achieve the goal I used the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116976/973158).

With slightly adapting the approach, my dataframe looks like this:

```
A   B   score           sets
1   2   6-1 6-2         6-1
1   2   6-1 6-2         6-2
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     6-4
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     4-6
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     6-3
```

However, I would also like to have another additional column which represents the number of the set per match. It is like a cumulative count of the sets per match. My question is, how can the above linked solution be changed in order to get the desired result which looks as follows:

```
A   B   score           sets    setnumber
1   2   6-1 6-2         6-1     1
1   2   6-1 6-2         6-2     2
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     6-4     1
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     4-6     2
3   4   6-4 4-6 6-3     6-3     3
```

I think somewhere in the following code lines an adaption needs to be done, but I couldn't figure out, yet, how it should work:

```
s = df['score'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1) # to line up with df's index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `repeat` and then `cumcount`

```
In [2915]: dff = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])['score'].repeat(
                            df['score'].str.split(' ').str.len()
                                 ).reset_index()

In [2916]: dff
Out[2916]:
   A  B        score
0  1  2      6-1 6-2
1  1  2      6-1 6-2
2  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3
3  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3
4  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3

In [2917]: dff.assign(setnumber=dff.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount()+1)
Out[2917]:
   A  B        score  setnumber
0  1  2      6-1 6-2          1
1  1  2      6-1 6-2          2
2  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3          1
3  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3          2
4  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3          3
```

You could also get `dff` with `.loc`

```
In [2923]: df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['score'].str.split(' ').str.len())]
Out[2923]:
   A  B        score
0  1  2      6-1 6-2
0  1  2      6-1 6-2
1  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3
1  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3
1  3  4  6-4 4-6 6-3
```

Comment: I just got to this solution. is there any difference? `df['setnumber'] =  df.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount() + 1`

Comment: Not much, `assign` returns a copy, your method sets it to `df`.