# How can I multiply row under certain condition with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I multiply row under certain condition with Pandas?
The condition is only a name ending with `Pref.` . 
Sort order do not mind.

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

df = pd.DataFrame({"area": ["Aomori Pref.", "Saitama", "GifuPref."],
                    "x": [30, 40, 55],
                    "y": ["l", "m", "n"]})

# I want to get:
#    area         x     y
# 0  Aomori       30    l
# 1  Aomori Pref. 30    l
# 2  Saitama      40    m
# 3  Gifu         55    n
# 4  GifuPref.    55    n
```

```

Comment: Can you explain more your conditions?

Comment: Thanks, the condition is only a name ending with `Pref.`

Comment: And `GifuPref.` - there is no space? like `Gifu Pref.`

Comment: No space. Then I could't use this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) values ending by `Pref.` and add new new column `b` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for `NaN`s for not matched values:

```
df1 = df['area'].str.replace('\s*(Pref.$)','').to_frame('a')
df1['b'] = df['area'].mask(df1['a'] == df['area'])

print (df1)
         a             b
0   Aomori  Aomori Pref.
1  Saitama           NaN
2     Gifu     GifuPref.
```

Then create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), give name to `Series` for new column name and last remove second level of `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
s = df1.stack().rename('area').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (s)
0          Aomori
0    Aomori Pref.
1         Saitama
2            Gifu
2       GifuPref.
Name: area, dtype: object
```

Remove orifinal column `area` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `s`, last for unique `index` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df.drop('area', 1).join(s).reset_index(drop=True)[df.columns]
print (df2)
           area   x  y
0        Aomori  30  l
1  Aomori Pref.  30  l
2       Saitama  40  m
3          Gifu  55  n
4     GifuPref.  55  n
```

---

Regex `\s*(Pref.$)` means - `\s*` is at least zero times, then match string in `()` and `$` means end of string.

Comment: Can you please explain the regex you used inside the replace function?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot

Comment: Elegant codes. Those worked well.Thank you very much for your gentle explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = "\s?Pref\\.$"
m = df.area.str.contains(pattern, regex=True)
tmp = df.copy()
tmp.loc[m,"area"] = tmp.area.str.replace(pattern, "")
(pd.concat([df, tmp])
   .sort_values("area")
   .drop_duplicates()
   .reset_index(drop=True))            

           area   x  y
0        Aomori  30  l
1  Aomori Pref.  30  l
2          Gifu  55  n
3     GifuPref.  55  n
4       Saitama  40  m
```

Comment: `m` is mask dataframe, I see, Thank you very much!

Comment: I left out `m`!  Sorry about that, yes it's a mask.  See updated answer.