# Dask dataframe - split column into multiple rows based on delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dask

What is an efficient way of splitting a column into multiple rows using dask dataframe? For example, let's say I have a csv file which I read using dask to produce the following dask dataframe:

```
id var1 var2
1  A    Z,Y
2  B    X
3  C    W,U,V
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
id var1 var2
1  A    Z
1  A    Y
2  B    X
3  C    W
3  C    U
3  C    V
```

I have looked into the answers for [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/28182629#28182629) and [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows/21032532).

I tried applying the answer given in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17116976/7275290 but dask does not appear to accept the expand keyword in str.split.

I also tried applying the vectorized approach suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/7275290 but then found out that np.repeat isn't implemented in dask with integer arrays (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2946).

I tried out a few other methods in pandas but they were really slow - might be faster with dask but I wanted to check first if anyone had success with any particular method. I'm working with a dataset with over 10 million rows and 10 columns (string data). After splitting into rows it'll probably become ~50 million rows.

Thank you for  looking into this! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dask allows you to use pandas directly for operations that are row-wise (like this) or can be applied one partition at a time. Remember that a Dask dataframe consists of a set of Pandas dataframes.

For the Pandas case you would do this, based on the linked questions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "Z,Y"], ["B", "X"], ["C", "W,U,V"]], 
    columns=['var1', 'var2'])
df.drop('var2', axis=1).join(
    df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).rename('var2'))
```

so for Dask you can apply exactly the same method via `map_partitions`, because each row is independent of all others. This maybe would look cleaner if the function passed were written out separately, rather than as a lambda:

```
d = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)
d.map_partitions(
    lambda df: df.drop('var2', axis=1).join(
        df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).rename('var2')))
```

if you did `.compute()` on this, you would get exactly the same result as for the Pandas case above. Likely you will *not* want to compute your massive dataframe in one go like that, but perform further processing on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
>>> df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True),columns=['var2 '])).drop('var2',1)
            .rename(columns=str.strip)
   id var1 var2
0   1    A    Z
0   1    A    Y
1   2    B    X
2   3    C    W
2   3    C    U
2   3    C    V
>>>
```

Or if need to reset the index:

```
>>> df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()                     
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True),columns=['var2 '])).drop('var2',1)
            .rename(columns=str.strip).reset_index(drop=True)
   id var1 var2
0   1    A    Z
1   1    A    Y
2   2    B    X
3   3    C    W
4   3    C    U
5   3    C    V
>>>
```

To a dask dataframe:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd 
sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=6)
```

Timings (literally the same):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True),columns=['var2 '])).drop('var2',1)
            .rename(columns=str.strip),number=10) # U9-Forward
0.05815268672555618
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: df.drop('var2', axis=1).join(
    df.var2.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).rename('var2')),number=10) # mdurant
0.05137591577754108
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this uses only pandas, not dask and thus does not parallelize.

Comment: @MatějRačinský Edited mine.

Comment: the point is to perform the operation using dask and thus doing so effectively (on some small dataset with 6 rows you quite can't see it, with > million rows it's way more notable), not calculate it using python and then transforming it to dask.