# Dask DataFrame - split multiple string columns based on delimiter into multiple rows simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a large Dask DataFrame that looks something like this:

| CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT | Consequence | Ensembl_geneid | Ensembl_proteinid | Ensembl_transcriptid | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 | 1-10000-A-C | A | C | con11,con12,con13 | gene11,.,gene13 | prot11,.,prot13 | tra11,.,tra13 |  |
| 1 | 11000 | 1-11000-A-G | A | G | con21 | gene21 | prot21 | tra21 |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | .,.,.,.,. | .,.,.,.,. | .,.,.,.,. | .,.,.,.,. |  |
| etc |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

All columns have been deliberately read as strings using the Dask DataFrame `read_csv(dtypes_mapping)`. The actual data is basically variant annotation data generated using the VEP tool, with a few million rows & about 90-100 columns in total, if that helps.

Each variant (i.e., CHROM, POS, ID, REF, ALT) has one or more comma-separated values corresponding to different effects. The "dots" are strings that the tool uses to represent missing values, which I would later replace with the proper `NaN` values.

There may be partial or complete missingness, but for each variant, there will always be the same number of positional values in each of the comma-separated string columns (they're meant to match up). E.g.,

- all "11" values match up,
- "con12" matches up with the missing values from the other columns, & so on.

I wanted to apply the Dask `Series.str.split(pat=delim, n=-1, expand=False)` & Dask `DataFrame.explode(column=col_list)` method to convert the data to long form while maintaining the positional value match-up, something like this:

| CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT | Consequence | Ensembl_geneid | Ensembl_proteinid | Ensembl_transcriptid | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10000 | 1-10000-A-C | A | C | con11 | gene11 | prot11 | tra11 |  |
| 1 | 10000 | 1-10000-A-C | A | C | con12 | . | . | . |  |
| 1 | 10000 | 1-10000-A-C | A | C | con13 | gene13 | prot13 | tra13 |  |
| 1 | 11000 | 1-11000-A-G | A | G | con21 | gene21 | prot21 | tra21 |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | . | . | . | . |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | . | . | . | . |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | . | . | . | . |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | . | . | . | . |  |
| 2 | 20000 | 2-20000-T-C | T | C | . | . | . | . |  |
| etc |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

When I try the whole thing in Pandas using a test sample, I can see using `.iloc[]` & `type()` that after the Pandas `Series.str.split()`, Pandas DataFrame recognises individual values as `list[str]`. This then allows Pandas `DataFrame.explode()` to work as intended.

However, I can't get the same to work in Dask. Dask DataFrame seems to take individual values after the Dask `Series.str.split()` as `str` instead of `list[str]` (`"['con11', 'con12', 'con13']"` instead of `['con11', 'con12', 'con13']`). This results in Dask `DataFrame.explode()` doing essentially nothing.

This is what I've been referring to, but I'm not sure the accepted solution would work in my case: [Dask dataframe - split column into multiple rows based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271941/dask-dataframe-split-column-into-multiple-rows-based-on-delimiter/54636224)

I can't tell if I'm missing something really obvious, or if it's a Dask design restriction. Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT**: Apologise for the delay @GuillaumeEB, I haven't been able to get back to this particular problem in the last week or so. Here's a small reproducer based on the above example:

```
### python = 3.12.1 (conda-forge)
### numpy = 1.26.3 (conda-forge)
### pandas = 2.1.4 (conda-forge)
### dask = 2023.12.1 (conda-forge)

import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as ddf

reqd_cols = ["Consequence", "Ensembl_geneid", "Ensembl_proteinid", "Ensembl_transcriptid"]

### Pandas implementation start, works as intended
df  = pd.DataFrame({
    "CHROM": [1, 1, 2],
    "POS": [10000, 11000, 20000],
    "ID": ["1-10000-A-C", "1-11000-A-G", "2-20000-T-C"],
    "REF": ["A", "A", "T"],
    "ALT": ["C", "G", "C"],
    "Consequence": ["con11,con12,con13", "con21", ".,.,.,.,."],
    "Ensembl_geneid": ["gene11,.,gene13", "gene21", ".,.,.,.,."],
    "Ensembl_proteinid": ["prot11,.,prot13", "prot21", ".,.,.,.,."],
    "Ensembl_transcriptid": ["tra11,.,tra13", "tra21", ".,.,.,.,."]
})

for col in reqd_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(pat=",", expand=False)

df = df.explode(column=reqd_cols, ignore_index=True)

print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df.head())
### Pandas implementation end

### Dask implementation start, does not work
df = ddf.from_pandas(
    data=pd.DataFrame({
        "CHROM": [1, 1, 2],
        "POS": [10000, 11000, 20000],
        "ID": ["1-10000-A-C", "1-11000-A-G", "2-20000-T-C"],
        "REF": ["A", "A", "T"],
        "ALT": ["C", "G", "C"],
        "Consequence": ["con11,con12,con13", "con21", ".,.,.,.,."],
        "Ensembl_geneid": ["gene11,.,gene13", "gene21", ".,.,.,.,."],
        "Ensembl_proteinid": ["prot11,.,prot13", "prot21", ".,.,.,.,."],
        "Ensembl_transcriptid": ["tra11,.,tra13", "tra21", ".,.,.,.,."]
    }),
    npartitions=1
)

for col in reqd_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(pat=",", n=-1, expand=False)

df = df.explode(column=reqd_cols)

print(df.info(verbose=True))
print(df.head())
### Dask implementation end
```

Comment: Could you build some reproducer with a small generated sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Dask 2023.7.1](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/changelog.html#v2023-7-1):

> Dask DataFrame to automatically convert text data using object data types to string[pyarrow] if pandas>=2 and pyarrow>=12 are installed.

In order to avoid this, you can deactivate this before creating your Dask Dataframe, just add:

```py
import dask
dask.config.set({"dataframe.convert-string": False})
```

before you create yours, and it fixes the problem.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much, I had no idea that "object" & "string[pyarrow]" were different somehow. I'll mark this answer as the accepted.