# Explode a row based on bullet points

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a `df` which have a column called `Description` and it has values like:

```
ID   Description
1    (a) this is good (b) bad (c) average
2    Ok
3    i am rahul works on (a) stack overflow (b) stack exchange
```

**Expected DF:**

```
 ID      Description
1        (a) this is good
1        (b) bad
1        (c) average
2        Ok
3        i am rahul works on (a) stack overflow
3        (b) stack exchange
```

I have seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows) which explodes column basis on separators but I need to explode based on bullet points.

Comment: `regex` might be helpful here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way, adapted from one of your links:

```
>>> df['Description'].str.split(r'.(?=\(.\))',expand = True).stack() 
ID
1   0       (a) this is good
    1                (b) bad
    2            (c) average
2   0                     Ok
3   0    i am rahul works on
    1     (a) stack overflow
    2     (b) stack exchange
```

Just using a `lookahead` regular expression to split on. The split on the 3d id is a bit different since you are not really splitting there.

Comment: @kabanus @jezrael: This works well!! Thanks!! Just one more thing if I there is else like `(i)` or `(ii)` but I dont want to split on these things!! I only want to split when there is a letter in between brackets and no numbers!!. Can this solution be tweaked

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Use `.(?=\([a-zA-Z]\))` - and lookup Python `re`.