# split rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I stuck with the problem how to divide a pandas dataframe by row,

I have a similar dataframe with a column where values are separated by \r\n and they are in one cell,

```py
    Color                              Shape  Price
0  Green  Rectangle\r\nTriangle\r\nOctangle     10
1   Blue              Rectangle\r\nTriangle     15
```

I need to divide this cell into several cells with the same values as other columns, e.g.

```py
   Color      Shape  Price
0  Green  Rectangle     10
1  Green   Triangle     10
2  Green   Octangle     10
3   Blue  Rectangle     15
4   Blue    Tringle     15
```

How do I do it well?

Comment: Try `df.Shape.str.split(expand=True).stack()`.  Does that help?

Comment: look at [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) after the split

Comment: @anky_91 explode() was added in version 0.25, is there any other way to solve in older versions?

Comment: @vb_rises : check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939

Answer (score 16):

You can do:

```
df["Shape"]=df["Shape"].str.split("\r\n")
print(df.explode("Shape").reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Color    Shape   Price
0   Green   Rectangle   10
1   Green   Triangle    10
2   Green   Octangle    10
3   Blue    Rectangle   15
4   Blue    Triangle    15
```

Comment: I tried this with a sample df and I got AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'. Do you have some library you imported that allows you to do that?

Comment: I think you are using different `pandas` version. `explode` was introduced in `0.25` onwards.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, I have 0.24, I will have to update pandas

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the most efficient way to do it but I can confirm that it works with the sample df:

```
data = [['Green', 'Rectangle\r\nTriangle\r\nOctangle', 10], ['Blue', 'Rectangle\r\nTriangle', 15]]   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Color', 'Shape', 'Price'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Color', 'Shape', 'Price'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    split = row['Shape'].split('\r\n')
    for shape in split:
        new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Color':[row['Color']], 'Shape':[shape], 'Price':[row['Price']]}))

new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   Color Price      Shape
0  Green    10  Rectangle
1  Green    10   Triangle
2  Green    10   Octangle
3   Blue    15  Rectangle
4   Blue    15   Triangle
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you'll need to split the Shape by white spaces, that will give you list of shapes. Then, use `df.explode` to unpack the list and create new rows for each of them

```
df["Shape"] = df.Shape.str.split()
df.explode("Shape")
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented, `str.split()` followed by `explode` is helpful. If you are not on Pandas 0.25, then you can use `melt` afterward:

```
(pd.concat( (df.Shape.str.split('\r\n', expand=True), 
            df[['Color','Price']]),
          axis=1)
   .melt(id_vars=['Color', 'Price'], value_name='Shape')
   .dropna()
)
```

Output:

```
   Color  Price variable      Shape
0  Green     10        0  Rectangle
1   Blue     15        0  Rectangle
2  Green     10        1   Triangle
3   Blue     15        1   Triangle
4  Green     10        2   Octangle
```