# How to split rows in a dataframe based on column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rows

I am trying to split my rows into multiple rows based on if a value exists in a column. I am able to filter based on the column value but would like to split the row into two based on the condition and return only specific parts of the row. The dataframe consists of different types of payments and the activity field represents the payment type that occurred. I would like for when there is a specific payment type to split the row into two. In the example below, when payment 2 exists I want it to be a separate transaction.

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID      Payment 1      Payment 2      Payment 3    Payment 4    Payment 5      Activity 
1          10             0              0            0              0         Payment 1  
2          0              10             15           0              0         Payment 2, Payment 3
3          10             20             30           0              0         Payment 1, Payment 2, Payment 3
```

But I would like for the dataframe to be:

```
ID      Payment 1      Payment 2      Payment 3    Payment 4    Payment 5       Activity 
 1          10             0              0            0              0         Payment 1  
 2          0              10             0            0              0         Payment 2
 2          0              0              15           0              0         Payment 3
 3          10             0              30           0              0         Payment 1, Payment 3
 3          0              20             0            0              0         Payment 2
```

Comment: prob much better way but you could do a `str.split(expand=True)` on `"Payment 2,"` and `", Payment 2"`. That way you have a column of payment 2's when they exist

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you want to change both the `Payment` columns and the `Activity` column at the same time. So actually, I only see the naive approach of iterating through the DataFrame and writing new rows to a new DataFrame depending on the condition `row['Payment 2'] == 0` like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Payment 1', 'Payment 2', 'Payment 3', 'Payment 4', 'Payment 5', 'Activity'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['Payment 2'] == 0:
    df_new = df_new.append(row)
  else:
    row_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[row['ID']], 'Payment 1':[row['Payment 1']], 'Payment 2':[0], 'Payment 3':[row['Payment 3']], 'Payment 4':[row['Payment 4']], 'Payment 5':[row['Payment 5']], 'Activity':[', '.join([x for x in ['Payment 1', 'Payment 3', 'Payment 4', 'Payment 5'] if row[x] != 0])]})
    df_new = df_new.append(row_new)
    row_new = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[row['ID']], 'Payment 1':[0], 'Payment 2':[row['Payment 2']], 'Payment 3':[0], 'Payment 4':[0], 'Payment 5':[0], 'Activity':'Payment 2'})
    df_new = df_new.append(row_new)
```

This will append two new rows (one with `Payment 2` only and one with the rest) if there is a `Payment 2` and append the original row from the source DataFrame if there is no `Payment 2`.

Related questions on splitting rows (based on one column only and leaving the other ones untouched):

- [split rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523316/split-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)
- [pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows)