# explode multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have to below dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([{"name": "John", 
                   "item" : "item1||item2||item3", 
                   "itemVal" : "item1Val||item2Val||item3Val"}, 
                  {"name" : "Tom", 
                   "item":"item4", 
                   "itemVal" : "item4Val"
                  }
                 ])
```

The dataframe is like this:

```
   name                 item                       itemVal
   John  item1||item2||item3  item1Val||item2Val||item3Val
    Tom                item4                      item4Val
```

I want to explode the row into multiple rows so that it will be like this (note that the `item` and its `itemVal` need to match).

```
   name                 item                       itemVal
   John                item1                      item1Val
   John                item2                      item2Val
   John                item3                      item3Val
    Tom                item4                      item4Val
```

I have looked at other answers here:

[Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

[pandas: How do I split text in a column into multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows)

But the works on only one column. How do I make it work on multiple columns? I'm using Pandas 1.0.1 and Python 3.8

Comment: Is it always the case that item and itemVal have the same number of partitions?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Yes always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = a.apply(lambda x: [v.split('||') for v in x]).apply(pd.Series.explode)
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
   name   item   itemVal
0  John  item1  item1Val
0  John  item2  item2Val
0  John  item3  item3Val
1   Tom  item4  item4Val
```

EDIT: If you want to split only selected columns, you can do:

```
exploded = a[['item', 'itemVal']].apply(lambda x: [v.split('||') for v in x]).apply(pd.Series.explode)
print( pd.concat([a['name'], exploded], axis=1) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this works. However, is there a way to specify the only columns I want to split?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) can achieve the split into rows. Since this involves strings, and more importantly no numerical computation, you should get faster speeds in Python, than running it in Pandas:

```
from itertools import product,chain
combine = chain.from_iterable

#pair item and itemval columns
merge = zip(df.item,df.itemVal) 

#pair the entires from the splits of item and itemval
merge = [zip(first.split("||"),last.split("||")) for first, last in merge]

#create a Cartesian product with the name column
merger = [product([ent],cont) for ent, cont in zip(df.name,merge)]

#create your exploded values
res = [(ent,*cont) for ent, cont in combine(merger)]
pd.DataFrame(res,columns=['name','item','itemVal'])

    name    item    itemVal
0   John    item1   item1Val
1   John    item2   item2Val
2   John    item3   item3Val
3   Tom     item4   item4Val
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as fast as the answer Sammywemmy suggested, nonetheless here is a generic function which works using Pandas functions. Note that explode function works only on one column at a time. So:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [['a','b'], ['c','d']], 'C': [['z','y'], ['x','w']]})

A    B     C
--------------
1 [a, b] [z, y]
2 [c, d] [x, w]

##Logic for multi-col explode
list_cols = {'B','C'}
other_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(list_cols))
exploded = [df[col].explode() for col in list_cols]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_cols, exploded)))
df2 = df[other_cols].merge(df2, how="right", left_index=True, right_index=True)

A B C
------
1 a z
1 b y
2 c x
2 d w
```