# Explode multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, unnest

I have researched this problem and found out that Pandas' explode function does not work on multiple columns, however, I have seen a few questions submitted on StackOverflow however, none of them seem to work for me.

**Dataset:**

```
j = { 
    "_id" : "5c45", 
    "user" : 5, 
    "ids" : [
        "1019", 
        "1021", 
        "1162"
    ], 
    "roles" : ["2d7f"]
}
```

**Current Script:**

```
root = json_normalize(j)
x = (root.applymap(type) == list).all()
y = x.index[x].tolist()
root = root.apply(lambda x: [str(v).split(',') for v in x]).apply(pd.Series.explode)

print(root)
```

I tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844022/python-pandas-explode-multiple-rows), but I get a value error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

**Expected Result:**

```
_id,user,ids,roles
5c45,5,1019,2d7f
5c45,5,1021,2d7f
5c45,5,1162,2d7f
```

Is there a simple, yet effective workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `record_path` and `meta` options:

```
pd.json_normalize(j, record_path=['ids'], meta=['_id','user','roles'])
```

Output:

```
      0   _id user roles
0  1019  5c45    5  2d7f
1  1021  5c45    5  2d7f
2  1162  5c45    5  2d7f
```

---

For a somewhat dynamic solution, try flatten the singletons:

```
pd.DataFrame({k:v[0] if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 1 else v
              for k,v in j.items()
             })
```

Comment: is there a dynamic version of this, without explicitly specifying the column names, as it may differ from each json object?