# Duplicating Row Based on Cell Value/Content

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Currently attempting this with Pandas, but if there is a better way I'm all ears. I have a csv file that looks something like this:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value1, value2 |
| value | value |

What I would like to do is:

1. Check column2 for rows that have more than one value (e.g. "value, value").
2. Create a new row with value2 and remove it from it's original row:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value1 |
| value | value2 |
| value | value |

I'm not sure what is the best way to determine if a cell in column2 has 2 values, maybe something like this:

```
for i in df.column2:
    if "," in i:
```

But I'm not sure how to capture that row and write it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas: explode multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844022/python-pandas-explode-multiple-rows)

Comment: Also if you don't get it from the duplicate that I posted, you could do: `df.assign(column2=df['column2'].str.split(',')).explode('column2')`

Comment: @SomeDude that ended up working great, thank you