# Splitting text to multiple rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, text, split

I'm working on big text data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  CustomerName     topics_seq  topics_count   log  
812199329          ['Due'/'Shift']      2     ["Agent: Hello", "Customer: Hello: Can you help?"] 
813447595          ['Shift']            1     ["Customer: Alright let's go", "Agent: Due to"]
```

I would like to split, to a new row the log column for each agent or customer, so something like this:

```
ID  CustomerName     topics_seq  topics_count   log  
812199329.1          ['Due'/'Shift']      2     ["Agent: Hello",
812199329.2          ['Due'/'Shift']      2     "Customer: Hello: Can you help?"]
813447595.1          ['Shift']            1     ["Customer: Alright let's go",
813447595.2          ['Shift']            1     "Agent: Due to"]
```

I wrote something like that but this is not what I wanted:

```
df = df['log'].str.split('Agent|Customer', '/n')
```

Please help.

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/how-to-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows

Comment: df.explode("log") ?

Comment: is the example the same as your actual data? is it a simple as exploding by the comma?

Comment: I saw that post but mine is different, I need to split text and base on condition (split after every agent/customer). df.explode("log") didn't do anything. Any suggestion? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Explode the log column:

```
df.explode('log')
```

Comment: Did not do anything, the log column did not get split. Is there a way to split by condition, after every agent/customer is mentioned?